# How to send http / https request in private EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have VPC with two subnets (PublicSubnet, PrivateSubnet). 1 EC2 instance in private subnet and 1 in public subnet. and my application is running on private ec2 instance. How can i send http / https request to private ec2 instance from public instance.

Comment: Inside the VPC all instances can connect to each other, you just need to make sure your route table is correct configured.

Comment: NAT gateway has to be attached to PRIVATE subnet. You attach Internet Gateway to PUBLIC subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scenario covered in AWS docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send HTTP/HTTPS requests from public instance to private instance,

1. Get the `Group ID` of the Security Group (e.g. `sg-0f991f56b81xxxxx`) attached to **public** instance.
2. Set this `Group ID` to Inbound Rules of the Security Group that is attached to **private** instance.

Do these procedures for both HTTP and HTTPS respectively.

Comment: Still not working....

I created one bastion host and one nat gateway in pub subnet and one ec2 instance in private subnet. I can use ssh forward to the private ec2 instance thru bastion host w/o any issue. The issue is in the private ec2 I can not reach internet.

Comment: NAT gateway has to be attached to PRIVATE subnet. You attach Internet Gateway to PUBLIC subnet. –